# Call base function after properties are populated in child function

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm creating API service and want to call function from BaseRequest after, all properties from child class are populated.

For instance

```
 public abstract class BaseRequest
{
    public void OnInitialize()
    {
        // I want to get parameters value from child class via 
        // reflection but don't know how to call this function after properties are populated
    }
}

public class ChildRequest : BaseRequest
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I can't use constructor because it's called before properties are populated. Is it possible to call method after child class is populated?

Comment: Only clients of your class know when they're done setting all properties, so you'd always be dependent on some external party calling a method. And in that case, why not mandate they call that method on `ChildRequest`, where all the properties are available? Alternatively, feed an instance of `ChildRequest` to the constructor of some other class, so only "completed" instances come in. Getting the properties of the child class from the base is easy (`this.GetType().GetProperties()`), but it doesn't sound like that's going to solve your problem.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y-problem to me. What do you want to achieve with the behavior?

Comment: Don't use inheritance when designing DTOs. Keep DTO types flat. Yes, it's a pain, but using inheritance for repetitive members is almost always a mistake. Also, use constructors, not mutable properties.

Comment: So it's seems like it's much easier to create static class and call it in controller after ChildRequest class is populated. I just wanted to "automate" it in base class but it;s seems like it's to much hassle with this

Comment: well i don't want to use BaseRequest for repetitive members but to get some data that is needed for db query. Like if it has FirstName then it automatically add to query this kind of line "xxxxx where FirstName = 'XYZ'". I'm quite bond to old schema of db

Comment: What do you mean by "static class"?

Comment: @Krystian "Like if it has FirstName then it automatically add to query this kind of line "xxxxx where FirstName = 'XYZ'"." - that kind of behaviour certainly _does not belong_ in a DTO at all because back-end query-generation is a completely separate concern from the font-end's DTO types. If you use EF then you don't need to do any of that anyway.

Comment: I'm using Dapper because database need to stay the same. Issue is that db schema is quite ancient and I can't really mess with it because it's quite easy to break thinks